# Trouble handling HTTP responses and parsing JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, http, parsing

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to solve an issue with the following code where a web client application receive back some JSON data from a web service application that uses a Rack middleware in order to respond.

In the web client app model I have

```
response_parsed = JSON.parse(response.body)
if response_parsed["account"]
  ...
else
  return response
end
```

In the above code the `response.body` come back from the web service app that uses a Rack middleware to respond to the web client:

```
accounts = Account.where(:id => ids)
[200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, accounts.to_json] # That is, response.body = accounts.to_json
```

Data transmission is ok, but I get the following error

```
TypeError
can't convert String into Integer

*Application Trace* 
lib/accounts.rb:107:in `[]'
```

The line `107` corresponds to

```
if response_parsed["account"]
  ...
```

**Where and what is the problem? How to solve that?**

---

If I try to debug the `respons.body` I get

```
# Note: this is an array!
"[{\"account\":{\"firstname\":\"Semio\",\"lastname\":\"Iaven\"\"}}]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm saying something you already realize, forgive me.

It looks like your response is a one-element array with a hash in it as the first element. Because the response is an array, when you use the [] it is expecting a integer representing the index of the item in the array you'd like to access, and that is what the error message means--it expected that you'd tell it the integer value of the item you wanted, but instead you gave it a string.

If you instead do:

```
response_parsed[0]['account']
```

It seems like you'd get what you want.

Comment: Why the web service output is an array and not an hash? I would like to have back an hash as I have in other similar cases.

Comment: It looks to me like: accounts = Account.where(:id => ids) would return an array of results. "ids" seems to imply you could pass in an array of valid id's there. Just because there only happens to be one doesn't mean the function would stop returning results as an array. This is just my suspicion, though.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. To make my code works properly, maybe I must have a web service response of `"{\"account\":{\"firstname\":\"Semio\",\"lastname\":\"Iaven\"\"}}"` instead of `"[{\"account\":{\"firstname\":\"Semio\",\"lastname\":\"Iaven\"\"}}]"`. But the web service should simply return a JSON string in the `response.body`?

Comment: If you ask an array of objects to output itself to json, you get a json string representing an array with a json hash for each of the objects as the array items. It is still a string. When you transmit and later consume that json string, it will give you an array again.